Visualize mixed-effects model with binary dependent and binary independent variable
I'm trying to come up with an intuitive visualization of a mixed-effects model with a binary dependent variable and a binary independent variable as well as participant as random effect. What I've produced so far is this:

The code underlying the plot is this:
summary(m <- glmer(depvar ~ indvar + (indvar|raneff.pnp), data = df, family = "binomial"))

iv <- effect("indvar", m, xlevels = list(indvar=seq(0, 1, 0.05)))
preds.hyp <- data.frame(iv$x, PREDICTIONS=plogis(iv$fit), LOWER=plogis(iv$lower), UPPER=plogis(iv$upper))

par(mar = c(6,6,2,2))
plot(preds.hyp$indvar, preds.hyp$PREDICTIONS, type="l", lwd=3, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1),
     cex.axis = 0.9, cex.lab = 0.9, cex.main = 0.9,
     xaxt = "none",
     frame = FALSE)

axis(1, at = c(0,1), labels = c("no", "yes"))
grid()
polygon(c(preds.hyp$indvar, rev(preds.hyp$indvar)),
        c(preds.hyp$LOWER, rev(preds.hyp$UPPER)),
        col=rgb(0,0,0,35,maxColorValue=255), border=NA)

for (i in seq(nrow(ranef(m)[[1]]))) {
  lines(seq(0, 1, 0.05),
        # --------> Fixed effects intercept
        plogis(-2.1845 + ranef(m)[[1]][i,1] + 
                 # -----------------> Fixed effects slope
                 (seq(0, 1, 0.05)*(4.0703 +ranef(m)[[1]][i,2])) 
        ),
        col=rgb(0,0,0,70,maxColorValue=255))
}

The problem here is that the graph with the lines sloping upwards suggests there are degrees between "yes/no": the higher the independent variable the higher the dependent variable. The coding for both variables was, however, binary.
How can this graph be changed so that it reflects more adequately the binary nature of the variables? Or, what other visualization could be used for the model?
Data:
df <- structure(list(indvar = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L), depvar = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("YES", 
"NO"), class = "factor"), raneff.pnp = c("GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGl", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGl", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "KKKKKKKKKKr", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "KKKKKKKKKKr", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGl", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "KKKKKKKKKKr", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "IIIIIIIIIIIIt", 
"IIIIIIIIIIIIt", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", 
"AAAAAAAAAAAAAn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", 
"NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLn", "NNNNNNNNNNNr", 
"NNNNNNNNNNNr", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLo", "DDDDDDDDDDDDe", 
"DDDDDDDDDDDDe", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAo", 
"AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", 
"CCCCCCCCCCx", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCx", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", 
"AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCx", 
"AAAAAAAAAAo", "CCCCCCCCCCCCCCx", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", 
"GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "AAAAAAAAAAo", 
"SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "AAAAAAAAAAo", 
"SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "AAAAAAAAAAo", "SSSSSSSSSSd", 
"GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", 
"GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "GGGGGGGGGGGGGi", "SSSSSSSSSSd", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"JJJJJJJJJJJJy", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", "JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJd", 
"JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJd", "JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJd", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", 
"JJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJJd", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", "JJJJJJJJJJJJy", "LLLLLLLLLLn", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "LLLLLLLLLLn", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"LLLLLLLLLLn", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"LLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "CCCCCCCCCCCCd", 
"CCCCCCCCCCCCd", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLn", "LLLLLLLLLLn", 
"LLLLLLLLLLn", "OOOOOOOOOOOOm", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", "LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLl", 
"AAAAAAAAAAo", "XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX", "XXXX")), row.names = c(NA, 
337L), class = "data.frame")


What message are you trying to make across?
If its the model's predictions, then I'd argue there's nothing to plot.  Your sole result would be something like "Having x on indvar increases the probability of having y on depvar by p with a confidence interval of..." etc.  As you say, there is nothing in between "yes" and "no", nor between depvar 1 or 2, so there is nothing to plot about the model's outputs, other than the uncertainty around p.
